# Ajax query not connecting to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi i would just like to ask if i am doing the right way to code my ajax jquery. 
Prior to applying my ajax, my code is functioning the way i expected but now it does not seem to update my database. Hope you could help me. Novice in ajax here.

```js
echo "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='test_ajax'>";
    echo "<select name='id' id='form-option' class='test-only'>";
    echo '<option selected="selected">' .'Choose a User'. '</option>';
    
    foreach ($registeredUsers as $key => $value) {
      $registered = JFactory::getUser($value);
      echo '<option value="'.$registered->id.'">'.$registered->name.'</option>';
      
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input name='uploadedfile' type='file' id='custom-file-input' class='test-only' /> <br/>";
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="custom-submit-input" disabled="disabled" >';

    echo "</form>";
```

Here is my jQuery script. Trying to connect to my process.php

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  
  jQuery('#test_ajax').submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var user_name = jQuery("#id").val();
          var user_file = jQuery("#uploadedfile").val();
          var dataString = 'name=' + user_name + 'file=' + user_file;

           jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
             sweetAlert("You have successfuly uploaded a file."); 
            }
           });
          
          return false;
         });
  
 });
```

Here is my process.php file. I can't find the error in my ajax query

```js
$target_dir = "../portal-files/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
else
{
  if(isset($_POST['id']))
    {
      $selectedValue = $_POST['id'];
      
      $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            $query = "INSERT INTO table1 (user_id) VALUES ($selectedValue)";

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $result = $db->execute();
    }
  else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  data: { name: user_name , file: user_file},



if(isset($_POST['name']))
```